# Edit option is not display for template files in elfinder

Tags: elfinder

I am using elfinder to edit my files.It works fine to edit all files but in case of template file edit option not display.How can we give access to edit template file in elfinder?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to edit template files.In connector.php add this

```
  'additionalMimeMap'=>array(
 'tpl:application/vnd.groove-tool-template' => 'text/x-smarty' // '[ext]:  [Detected MIME Type]' => '[Normalized MIME Type]'
 ),
```

Now it can be used to edit template files.